# How to reset twitter-bootstrap-wizard without page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a JQuery application. I have 3 steps in twitter-bootstrap-wizard. Now what i want is to reset my twitter-bootstrap-wizard on submit click without page load so that the user view step1 with all HTML controls in step1 to it's initial state.

Comment: Can you please include your latest code in the question?

Comment: There is a form-wizard plugin of twitter-bootstrap-wizard. I need to reset that wizard. The HTML inside the wizard is too long. For simplicity, check this http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_2/form_wizard.html i need to reset my wizard to same view as you see during page load. ANd this should be done on submit click in step 4.